# deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: cordova-plugins

I am developing a hybrid app using ionic framework.
I am trying to saving the data locally using sqlite.
I installed cordova sqlite using CLI.
I am getting:
  an error Module com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin.SQLitePlugin does not exist.
  deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
  Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
  Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

I have read a lot of threads talking about this issue. All were pointing at the cordova.js.
I included it in my scripts but also nothing changed. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple Just Add the Plugin (*Solved For me)

cordova plugin add https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy.git

Answer (score 0):

`deviceready` event fires only once per webpage lifecycle.

This event is essential to any application. It signals that Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access.

Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code loads, a custom loading image displays.

However, JavaScript only loads once the DOM loads. This means the web app may potentially call a Cordova JavaScript function before the corresponding native code becomes available.

The `deviceready` event fires once Cordova has fully loaded.

*Credit for this answer goes to Mohamed Taman.*

Details: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Comment: '`deviceready` event fires only once per application lifecycle.` That is trivially *false*. If you reload your webpage within the same app, or navigate to a different one, `deviceready` fires again.